# Angular 2 site won't run in Windows Server 2016

Tags: angular, windows-server-2016

I'm following along in this video tutorial in order to learn how to deploy our Angular 2 site to a Windows Server 2016 machine:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JUYCDnqR8p0

Everything the video suggests works. I've got IISNode, Node Express, and the starter Angular 2 application all working.

Now I want to deploy my much more complex Angular 2 application. It was originally designed to run on Linux so I'm not sure what to tweak to get it to run on Windows Server 2016. I'm told I can just take the contents of dist and plop into into the website folder on Windows Server 2016. That's what I did.

When I browse to it on the server, however, I get this:

[image]

The stack trace tells me it got to server.js, so that's a good sign. Where things seem to be fouling up is when it looks for module.js. I did a search on the server for module.js and couldn't find it. The stack trace ends with a failure to find the module 'compression'. <-- I'm not sure what this is.

Here is my web.config:

```
<!-- indicates that the server.js file is a node.js application to be handled by the iisnode module -->
<handlers>
    <add name="iisnode" path="server/server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
</handlers>

<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="sendToNode">
            <match url="/*" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="server/server.js" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>

</system.webServer>
```

Can someone please help me troubleshoot this?

Comment: can you post the server.js file?

Comment: most likely this is due to webpack module if you have one in your project